# Tracing touches with touchesMoved in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I'm tracing my touch using the `touchesMoved` method in Swift, but my app crashes when I only swipe the screen. To be clear: when I hold the touch for a little while, and then move, it does not crash; when I just swipe immediately, it crashed with the runtime-error:

> locationInView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

My code looks like this:

```
   override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        println("MOVED")

        var aTouch: AnyObject = touches as AnyObject

        var location = aTouch.locationInView(self.imageViewer)

        self.textEdit.frame = CGRectMake(0, location.y, self.view.frame.width, 44)
    }
```

Any suggestions on why this happens would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Don't know why the `touchesBegan` method crashed, but I got the desired effect using a gesture recognizer like this:

```
func buttonLongPressed(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){

    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed{
    self.textEdit.frame = CGRectMake(0, gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.view).y, self.view.frame.width, 44)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you assigning touches (which is a Set) to aTouch variable:

```
var aTouch: AnyObject = touches as AnyObject
```

Try to change it to:

```
var aTouch: AnyObject = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
```